# Generate list of missing time intervals

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas Series where the are some missing data represented by nans, and would like to get an overview of for how long the the data is generally missing and how many times

An example would be:

```
10:01    1.23
10:02    2.23
10:03    nan
10:04    nan
10:05    nan
10:06    6.23
10:07    nan
10:08    nan
10:09    9.23
```

Then the desire output would be a list like this

```
missing = [[10:03,10:05], [10:07,10:08]]
N_missing = 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
#create DataFrame
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = ['A','B']

#boolean mask for check no NaNs to variable for reuse
m = df['B'].notnull()
#create index by cumulative sum for unique groups for consecutive NaNs
df.index = m.cumsum()

#filter only NaNs row and aggregate first and last value, convert to list
missing = df[~m.values].groupby(level=0)['A'].agg(['first','last']).values.tolist()
print (missing)
[['10:03', '10:05'], ['10:07', '10:08']]

#get length of nested lists
N_missing = len(missing)
print (N_missing)
2
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df[~m.values])
       A   B
B           
2  10:03 NaN
2  10:04 NaN
2  10:05 NaN
3  10:07 NaN
3  10:08 NaN
```

Similar solution with `Series`:

```
m = s.notnull()
cum = m.cumsum()
missing = s[~m.values].index.to_series().groupby(cum).agg(['first','last']).values.tolist()
print (missing)
[['10:03', '10:05'], ['10:07', '10:08']]

N_missing = len(missing)
print (N_missing)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

if columns of the dataframe are stored with these name

[image]

```
missing=df[np.isnan(f['value'])]
no_missing=len(missing)
```

missing

```
date     value
10:03    NaN
10:04    NaN
10:05    NaN
10:07    NaN
10:08    NaN
```

no_missing

```
5
```